# jquery, javascript скрипт скачивание большого кол-ва файлов из списка с паузой

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть HTML файл с 500.000 ссылок, какой будет самый не трудоемкий для браузера скрипт на Jquery или чистом javaScript - брать одну ссылку, скачивать файл по этой ссылке, ждать 3 секунды, потом брать другой файл из очереди и так до конца списка. При всем при этом сам HTML файл будет открыт в Tor Browser.

Comment: А зачем тратить на это свои 17 дней жизни?

Comment: иначе, скорее всего, забанят по ip)

Comment: можно все собрать и курлом с подделкой куков и прокси + sleep 2-3 sec., просто интересен способ более оптимальный, менее трудозатратный. Допустим механизм JS -> идет поиск через аналог for и обращение к каждому элементу <a> и скачивание файла, я это уже сделал и это работает) интересует самый НЕ затратный с точки зрения ресурсов способ, может кто занимался)